# My CSS won't apply to my html webpage

Tags: html, css

I recently downloaded Sublime Text 2 thinking it would streamline the process for a beginning coder like myself. And it did, up until my css file stopped taking effect. The html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
        <title>
        My Webpage Test
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the css looks like this:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

With simple CSS like this, I can't understand why the color (bright red) will not take effect! The webpage turns out a weird green color.

Please help!

EDIT: I figured it out. The problem was that I had two identically named css files. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post your code in your question, not pictures of your code.

Comment: I tried but it just became part of the body and looked very messy.

Comment: Are two files in the same directory?

Comment: We can help clean it up.

Comment: Yes, they are both contained within a single project folder.

Comment: Put something inbetween the body tags. Currently your body might be 0 x 0

Comment: In any case it should be white rather than "weird green" if your CSS is not applied.

Comment: Check that the css file is actually a css file. Press cmd and I with the file selected, and check that the file format is css.

Comment: OK I edited the question so that the code was there

Comment: It might be one of two things: body is empty (insert something between `<body>` and `</body>`) or css file is not being read: filename might be case sensitive or file might be in the wrong directory.

Comment: by "stopped taking effect" are you impliying that it was looking as it should and then it suddenly wasn't? take into account that your question is probably being downvoted because it is not clear enough: it helps to be as specific as you can and to explain what have you tried to do and what do you think the error is

Comment: I know you posted the CSS but reopen the stylesheet and make sure it doesn't contains rgb(0,255,0) instead of rgb(255,0,0) like in the code you posted, because that first is a bright green while the latter is red.

Comment: ithil: No, I mean originally I had it set to a pale green. I then changed it by adjusting the rgb values, but it has stayed as the same pale green color.

Comment: so originally you saw the pale green but you changed it and your change doesn't show up. Maybe a problem refreshing? Where are you trying to look at it, locally or are you uploading it to a server? Also check @Chad answer and make sure you're not missing anything basic

Comment: I guess OP realized it after I said "reopen the stylesheet" lol

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the filename is correct, and that it is the same case as in your code.

Reopen the stylesheet and make sure it doesn't contains rgb(0,255,0) instead of rgb(255,0,0) like in the code you posted, because that first is a bright green while the latter is red.

Or, you could just do `background: red;` in your css.

Lastly, you may have a caching issue. Force refresh the page with Ctrl+Shift+R or Ctrl+F5 (depending on your browser).

To those of you saying to make sure the body has content, the body does not need a `p` tag or anything else for this to work. The body tag defaults to the visible area.

Comment: I would only add, also make sure the path to your css file is correct

Comment: Yes though I left that out because OP said in a comment that the files are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

And change the name of css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
        <title>
        My Webpage Test
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a paragraph in the body. Example:

```
<body>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</body>
```